# Find print server on which a printer is installed using powershell in Domain

Tags: windows, powershell, printing, dns

I need to quickly find out the server on which a printer is installed in my Domain. There are 12 print servers with more than 50 printers on each. I used fol command but I get error

```
PS C:\>Get-Printer -Name "PayRoll_Sec_ptr"
```

But this command give me result only when used on the particular server on which the printer is installed. That means I have to write it on 12 servers (or till I get the server where the printer is installed"

When I used this command on my AD Role computer. it says

```
the term "get-printer" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 

 script file, or operable program.
```

Answer (score 2):

the `Get-Printer` cmdlet is one of the many that are not on earlier OSs. for instance, it is not available on win7ps5.1 at all.

you may want to use the CIM cmdlets to make the calls from your workstation. this ...

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_Printer -ComputerName 'LocalHost', '127.0.0.1'
```

will get the printers from the systems listed. you can feed it a list in the `-ComputerName` parameter to get info from all your print servers.

while it seems unlikely, you can use the WMI version of that command if you need to run it on a ps2.0 system.

Comment: I need to find a specific printer from a list of print servers and I need to find it out through port. I usually don't have share names for printers just an Ip and I have to find out the server where it is installed. appreciated please

Comment: the returned info contains both a `.ShareName` and a `.PortName` parameter. i don't have any shared printers - just one win7ps5.1 computer and a USB printer - so i cannot test to see if the `.PortName` contains the IP. i suspect that it does, tho. have you tried it? [*grin*]